# Asynctask - An error occurred while executing doInBackground()

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Customers reported crashes in the Play Store console. I did not use android-job and JobIntentServices in my app.
But the app throws following exception.

> Parcel.java line 2385
>
> android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull   Fatal Exception:
> java.lang.RuntimeException
>
> An error occurred while executing doInBackground Fatal Exception:
> java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing
> doInBackground()
> at android.os.AsyncTask$4.done(AsyncTask.java:415)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
>
> Caused by java.lang.SecurityException: Caller no longer running, last
> stopped +11s54ms because: timed out while starting
> at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2385)
> at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2369)
> at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2352)
> at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2294)
> at android.app.job.IJobCallback$Stub$Proxy.dequeueWork(IJobCallback.java:292)
> at android.app.job.JobParameters.dequeueWork(JobParameters.java:287)
> at androidx.core.app.JobIntentService$JobServiceEngineImpl.dequeueWork(JobIntentService.java:12)
> at androidx.core.app.JobIntentService.dequeueWork(JobIntentService.java:4)
> at androidx.core.app.JobIntentService$CommandProcessor.doInBackground(JobIntentService.java:2)
> at androidx.core.app.JobIntentService$CommandProcessor.doInBackground(JobIntentService.java:2)
> at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:394)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
>
> Caused by android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace: at
> com.android.server.job.JobServiceContext.assertCallerLocked(JobServiceContext.java:502)
> at
> com.android.server.job.JobServiceContext.doDequeueWork(JobServiceContext.java:380)
> at
> com.android.server.job.JobServiceContext$JobCallback.dequeueWork(JobServiceContext.java:161)
> at android.app.job.IJobCallback$Stub.onTransact(IJobCallback.java:169)
> at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1190)

Can anyone help me to identify and solve the issue?

Tried Solution - Replaced all the AsyncTask implementations with ExecutorServices. But not worked.